# Parsing XML from cURL request in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have read through many of the similar posts, but none seem to help me.  I am making a cURL request, which returns:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<Response>
<stats>
  <searchInput>Area Code=XXX, Phone Number=XXXXXXX, First Name=, Middle Name=, Last Name=, City=, State=</searchInput>
  <rows>1</rows>
</stats>
  <record>
    <firstname></firstname>
    <middlename></middlename>
    <lastname></lastname>
    <addressA></addressA>
    <addressB></addressB>
    <info>Not Found - Possible pre-paid or unregistered number</info>
    <phone>(XXX)XXX-XXXX</phone>
    <phone_carrier></phone_carrier>
    <provider_type></provider_type>
  </record>
</Response>
```

However when I try to access the data by

```
// Find record using phone number
$result = Search::find_by_number($area_code, $phone_num);
$result = json_decode($result);
```

and then use `$result->record->firstname` I get the error that trying to get property of non-object.  To me the XML looks valid, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: cURL output is xml not json

Comment: Next time please format your code samples properly...

Answer (score 0):

cURL output in xml format you can use [simplexml_load_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) to parse it :

```
// Find record using phone number
$result = Search::find_by_number($area_code, $phone_num);
$result = simplexml_load_string($result);
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I try that I get this error: Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

Comment: that mean your xml is invalid maybe there is space in begining of xml like ' <?xml'